# TaskCompletionSource for Task

Tags: c#, async-await

How do I create a `TaskCompletionSource` for a `Task` instead of a `Task<TResult>`?

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I rollbacked your edit because it changes the nature of the question in a non-intuitive way. If that's what the OP intended, they should edit it themself.

Comment: @Douglas My edit was just putting formatting in place - the original poster had `Task<TResult>`, but hadn't formatted it correctly.  I did not change *any* content.  Check the edit - all I did was add in the ``` characters appropriately.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: You're right; my apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no non-generic version.  However, [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) derives from [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), so you can just use `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` and return the task.

```
Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // Implement method as needed

    return tcs.Task; // Return the Task<bool> as a Task
}
```

Note that I'm using `bool` just because it's a small value type, and the result will get "thrown away".  Another option here is to make your own custom type and return that, ie:

```
private struct EmptyType {}

Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<EmptyType>();

    // Implement method as needed
    // Use tcs.SetResult(default(EmptyType)) or similar

    return tcs.Task; // Return the Task<bool> as a Task
}
```

The main advantage here is the type is the smallest possible (least waste), and a type that doesn't suggest there is a "value" contained within the result (if the consumer does use reflection, etc).